# Rotate UIImage with Unproportional Size and Frame Adjustment

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a container view with subviews and some subviews can be rotated within this view. What I want to do at the end, is take a screenshot of the entire view with rotated and non-rotated subviews. I choose to not use screenshot of the screen but rather process each element separately and create an image out of them and merge all images together. I do so for the purpose of screenshot being enlarged to original image. So...

Everything is achieved successfully except for those subviews which are rotated. Here is the code how I screenshot each subview:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(subview.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat angle = atan2(rte.transform.b, rte.transform.a);
CGContextRotateCTM (context, angle);
[subview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here is the problem with rotated subviews. Image below shows slightly rotated subview but its corners are cut off. In addition this image is shifted left. Compare left and right sides.

[image]
<sub>(source: [vunet.us](http://vunet.us/inc/img/test-rotate.png))</sub>

I think I understand that I am processing rotated image within a small original frame. But what is the fix for it? It seems a bit complex to calculate a precise frame size for any angle used. Isn't there some easier solution I am missing?

Comment: Looks like your layer is masking to bounds. Try disabling that.

Comment: I tried but same result. I suspect I draw within a small frame. I suspect I may need to shift image to the right as it is drawn shifted left.

Comment: @Vad I think you are wrong. Mask to Bounds is definitely the error here. Are you sure you tried disabling this on all layers? Including the views that this imageView is contained in? Also, the reason it is shifted to the left is because you have auto-layout enabled.